# Dataframe read from CSV file doesn't contain column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that looks something like this:

```
996_axis   996_flux
5100.0     0.8693662522326132
5100.5     0.92424271352166
5101.0     0.890126539973385
5101.5     1.3986609534526506
5102.0     0.9314980463849233
5102.500000000001     0.8787443384465012
5103.000000000001     0.938446925998305
5103.500000000001     0.9623687779700495
```

I am trying to read this in and get the two columns so I can plot it.

```
d["df_996"] = pd.read_csv('996.csv')
print(d["df_" + '996'].loc[:,"996_axis"])
```

Yet, trying this out leads to a KeyError:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you `print` the data frame? Just to see what it is reading exactly

Comment: Your file looks like `tab-delimited`.  You probably need to specify so, when reading it. Try `sep='\t'`.

Answer (score 2):

`pandas.read_csv` uses commas as the delimiter by default, so your parsed dataframe doesn't contain a column named `"996_axis"`. To read data that has a different separator, specify one.
For example:

```
d["df_996"] = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_in), delimiter=r"\s+")
print(d["df_" + '996'].loc[:,"996_axis"])
```

prints

```
0    5100.0
1    5100.5
2    5101.0
3    5101.5
4    5102.0
5    5102.5
6    5103.0
7    5103.5
Name: 996_axis, dtype: float64
```

If your data is tab-delimited, then specify `delimiter=r"\t"`, but `\s+` works too (`\s+` means one or more whitespace)

Comment: That's not what it is written on doc (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: @Buzz,  yes it is: _"sep str, **default ‘,’**
Delimiter to use. "_. `delimiter` is simply an alias for `sep`, but I prefer it because the `csv` module also uses `delimiter`

Comment: No, read the doc carefully. If not differently specified, a python engine using csv.Sniffer is used to infer the right delimiter. And in some case it can fail.

Comment: @Buzz No, the sniffer is used if the delimiter is set to `None`, which is *not* the default (as Pranav Hosangadi noted, the default is `,`).

Comment: To test this: not specifying `sep` gives one column: `['996_axis   996_flux']`; Specifying `sep=None` gives multiple: `['996_axis', 'Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2', '996_flux']`. Clearly `sep=None` is _not_ the default value. @Buzz